# ADF Copy Data, Sink all JSON Object into SQL Cell

Tags: azure, api, mapping, azure-data-factory, copy-data

I am using `copy data` **activity** in `Azure data factory (ADF)` to make calls to 5 different `APIs` in the loop and all 5 APIs will have 5 different responses.

The idea is to sink the whole JSON Object into the SQL database. I want to know how can I refer to all API JSON object responses.

For example, here is my API Response:

```
 {
     result:[{
    "elemenName":"Element Name",
     "elemenName":"Element Name",

   }]
   }
```

I do not want to sink the `result` in the database cell, but instead, I want to be able to sink the whole JSON object in the cell. I am not sure how to refer to this JSON object. my API JSON response is greater than 5MB

Answer (score 0):

- In for-each activity, you can use **lookup activity** to read the json API data and then use the **Script actvity** to insert the json data that is read from lookup activity into the SQL table. Below is the approach.
- In Lookup activity, select `HTTP` as linked service and `json` as source dataset.
- Enter the Base URL and in Relative URL, enter the value from for-each item as dynamic content.
- Then add a script activity and add the linked service for SQL database in it.
- Enter the query as a dynamic content in query text box.

```sql
Insert into <sink-table-name> values ('@{activity('Lookup2').output.value}')
```

[image: img]

- When pipeline is run, json data from each api is copied to table as separate rows.

[image]

**Update:**

> Message=The size of lookup activity result exceeds the limitation`

To resolve this, Inside for-each, use the copy activity and take the source dataset as delimited text with different column and row delimiter. In this case, I took **(``)** as both column and row delimiter, so that the entire Json response is in a single row.

[image: img1]

Copy the data to sink database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as mentioned above my data is greater than 5 MB, and this solution will not work for me.

I can think of using datacopy but then I will need a way to insert it in the database

Comment: **my data is greater than 5 MB**-- Is it throwing any error? Or Did data get truncated?
**I can think of using datacopy**-- What is datacopy?

Comment: I am getting an error, where it mentions is that my API JSON response is large and look-up cannot support it. my copy data is polling API response.. by data copy I meant copy data :)

``
ErrorCode=UserErrorComputePluginFailure,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The size of lookup activity result exceeds the limitation 4194304.,Source=,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Execution.Core.ExecutionException,Message=The size of lookup activity result exceeds the limitation``

Comment: Edited the answer with copy activity , since there is limitation in lookup activity

Comment: Hi Asim, thanks for the help, but the source is API not file. Your example is for source being a file.

Comment: You can use http connector

Comment: http connector doesn't provide similar options as the file source

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253156/discussion-between-aswin-and-manam).